# Compacts And The Reciprocal Of The Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

While I was studying Functional Analysis, this question arised:

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a subset with the propertie that, for all $f$ continuous ($f \in \mathcal{C}^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$), the image $f(K)$ has a global maximum (notice that if we consider $(-f)$, then it also has a global minimum). Is $K$ a compact subset?

We can, of course, try to generalize and conjecture and ask ourselves if $f$ being continuous only at the topological space induced by $K$, or if $K$ is any compact topological space, but for a while I am trying that "simple" question.

(If $K$ has "nice" properties, e.g. $K$ is a connected space, the answer is clear, but the general case is a sweet challenge to me.)

Comment: It's true that if every $f(K)$ is compact then $K$ is compact. I'll try to remember the proof.

Comment: @ZachStone well, if $f$ is the identity...

Comment: Oh, I didn't that $K$ is a subset of of $\mathbb{R}$. That makes it easier.

Comment: @mathgccunha Not quite what we were discussing the other day, but... in Elon's Espaços Métricos, in page 297, exercise 15: a metric space $M$ is compact if and only if every positive real function on $M$ has positive infimum. I wonder if there's a result like this for topological spaces.

Comment: But the hypothesis does not say $f(K)$ is compact, it only says $f(K)$ has global maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K$ is not bounded then the function $f(t)=|t|$ has no maximum on $K$.
If $K$ is not closed, say $x$ is in the closure but not in $K$; then
$f(t)=-|t-x|$ has no maximum on $K$.

(If the notation means you want bounded $f$ then $|t|/(1+|t|)$ and
$\max(-|t-x|,-1)$.)

Comment: After all, it was pretty simple, and an elegant solution. Great!